# Why does this recursion crash?

Tags: c, recursion

I want to generate random numbers between 0-4 in a matrix, ***check(x)*** checks wether ur allowed to assign ***x*** to that position, if not then ***-3*** is assigned instead.
while loop at the bottom is crashing my code, any ideas to fix this?

```
int Creat(int T[7][7],int i,int j){

    int x=rand()%5;
        switch(j){
            case 0: case 6:
                if(i==0||i==6){
                    if(T[i-1][j]==0||T[i][j-1]==0){
                        T[i][j]=(check(1))?1:-3;}
                    else{
                        T[i][j]=(check(x%2))?x%2:-3;
                        }
                    }
                else{
                    if(T[i-1][j]==0||T[i][j-1]==0){
                        T[i][j]=(check(x%2+1))?x%2+1:-3;}
                    else{
                        T[i][j]=(check(x%3))?x%3:-3;}
                }
            break;
            case 1:case 2:case 3:case 4:case 5:
                if(i==0||i==6){
                    if(T[i-1][j]==0||T[i][j-1]==0){
                        T[i][j]=(check(x%2+1))?x%2+1:-3;}
                    else{
                        T[i][j]=(check(x%3))?x%3:-3;}
                    }
                else{
                    if(T[i-1][j]==0||T[i][j-1]==0){
                        T[i][j]=(check(x%4+1))?x%4+1:-3;}
                    else{
                        T[i][j]=(check(x))?x:-3;}
                    }
            break;
            default: return rand()%5;
        }while(T[i][j]==-3){T[i][j]=Creat(T,i,j);}
    return T[i][j];
}
```

Comment: That  while loop is not conditional. That is to say, it runs every time the function is called, which then calls the function again. See the name of this place? "SO" - that's what you're getting. You just get deeper and deeper into recursion - none of the invocations of `Creat` ever finish...

Comment: @enhzflep it could stop if its generates the correct number, although I gather from what u said that this is poor coding, not wrong. As might stop but not fast enough to not crash.

Comment: For pity's sake, include newlines and space in your code.  It is almost unreadable as shown!  The line `}while(T[i][j]==-3){T[i][j]=Creat(T,i,j);}` actually contains a free-standing `while` loop after the close brace of a `switch` statement.

Comment: It looks to me as though you could either revise `check()` or wrap it so that you don't write the ternary operators in this function.  For example, you'd simply use `T[i][j] = revised_check(x % 4 + 1, -3);` where the first argument is returned if it OK and the second argument is returned if it is not.  That would cut down the complexity of this code.

Comment: my aim is to get rid of the ***-3***s (suitable num not found) , the code works just fine without recursion, but I have -3 in my matrix, `check()` prevents exceding the limit of numbers for ex(limit of ***0***s is 9 ***1***s is 17 etc.

Comment: I am so embarassed rn, guys! I replaced ***while*** with ***if*** and it worked, the reason I didn't do it before is that, I had replaced the ***-3***s with `Creat(T,i,j)` and it did nothing, so figured it would be the same thing, sorry for wasting u guy's precious time.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jonathan Leffler,@enhzflep the while loop is free-standing.

Replacing it with `if(T[i][j]==-3){...;}` fixes the problem.